Find a Basis of a plane $2x_1 - 3x_2 +4x_3 = 0$ such that co ordinate representation of the vector (1,2,1) is (2,3) in that basis.
Find a Basis of a plane $2x_1 - 3x_2 +4x_3 = 0$ such that co ordinate representation of the vector (1,2,1) is (2,3) in that basis.
I can easily get a basis for the plane by simply expressing $x_1$ in terms of $x_2$ and $x_3$, then putting $x_2 = 1$ and $x_3 = 0$ to one get of the basis vectors and by putting $x_2 = 0$ and $x_3 = 1$ we can get another basis vector.
Doing this, I am getting the following
$$\mathcal{B} = \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},
 \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$$
How do I preceed from here? My initial approach was to assume that there exist another basis for this plane, say $\mathcal{A} = \{a_1,a_2\}$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 2\\ 1
\end{pmatrix} = 2a_1 + 3a_2
$$
and then again express $a_1$ and $a_2$ in terms of $\mathcal{B}$ and then solve for appropriate constants. However I end up with having more variables than equations and the problem gets messy. I have also tried thinking about this problem in terms of Linear Transformations, where i come up with a matrix such that its column space is the given plane, and then apply change of basis transformations, however it doesn't work out.
Thank you for any help and hints in advance!

Figured it out.
We can see that the co ordinate representation of (1,2,1) in the derived basis is (1,1). Therefore, we can simply modify the basis $\mathcal{B} = \{b_1,b_2\}$ as $a_1 = \frac{1}{2}b_1$ and $a_2 =\frac{1}{3} b_2$, so that $2a_1 + 3a_2$ is simply $b_1 + b_2 = (1,2,1)^T$.
